# How to find record with integer value instead of string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, casting, type-conversion

I have **column field as string** for ex. start_age("20") and end_age("40").

Now I want user whose age(**24 as integer**) is between start_age and age_age. So How can I get this user?

I have tried with this query

```
User.where("start_age < (?) AND end_age > (?)", age, age)
```

but getting this error:

```
PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  operator does not exist: character varying < integer
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do write :

```
User.where("start_age::integer <= :age AND end_age::integer >= :age", age: age)
# or equivalent
User.where(":age BETWEEN start_age::integer AND end_age::integer", age: age)
```

Here is some *demo* :

```
test_dev=# select 20  between '1'::integer and '10'::integer as result;
 result
--------
 f
(1 row)

test_dev=# select 5  between '1'::integer and '10'::integer as result;
 result
--------
 t
(1 row)

test_dev=# select '12'::integer as number;
 number
--------
     12
(1 row)
```